# Concurrency limitations for Salesforce API?

Tags: salesforce, jsforce

I am running this code that uses `jsforce` to interact with Salesforce API.

In two different steps, one upserts into a collection, and the next step would require finding the object again in the collection. I'm failing to trigger the 2nd step occasionally, and according to my logs in these failure cases, the 2nd step triggered before the 1st step (upsert) responded.

I'm suspecting that Salesforce isn't allowing me to read that object when another operation is concurrently updating it. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: Have you tried running 2nd query with "FOR UPDATE" statement? Should wait for exclusive lock = most recent state of data. But can cause other issues if you have multiple operations trying to access same rows

Comment: @eyescream can you elaborate more on the "FOR UPDATE" statement? I'm using `jsforce` and calling `find` using `SObject`: https://jsforce.github.io/jsforce/doc/SObject.html

Comment: I'm talking about https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_for_update.htm. I had a quick look at the spec you linked and it seems jsforce tries to abstract the SOQL syntax from you, you build queries like in LINQ or some ORM system... There's chance jsforce didn't implement this bit so if you have no way to run "raw" SOQL you can't use this locking mechanism.

Comment: https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/search?q=%22FOR+UPDATE%22 doesn't return much. Looks like author "solved" concurency issues in their tests by making helper apex methods, exposing them as REST services and calling them instead of raw API access... Try opening an issue with the library creator asking for ideas / think if you can extend the library yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I did a bit of reading myself and figured that was the case with the jsforce library. I have already opened this issue with the library repository and we'll see what they have to say about it.....

Comment: My issue happens very occasionally as the 2nd step requires filling out some information. It only happens when I'm doing testing and while I'm filling out that information fairly rapidly (then the conflict occurs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I can simply wait for the 1st request to respond before proceeding or add an arbitrary timer prior to firing off the 2nd request to bypass this problem.

Marking this as solved as I've filed the question in the library's repository: https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/issues/1177